# VB.NET - New text editor? (Syntax Highlighting and Syntax Extraction)

Tags: vb.net, syntax

I'm thinking of developing a more efficient version of the Rich Text format but I need to know a little about **Syntax Highlighting and Syntax Extraction**.

Like when reading the file, read all the {Property Boxes} and use them in a RichTextBox.
Ex:
{C=0000FF}Hello world!{/C}
Prints "Hello world!" in red.

This would also be good to figure out because I am also building acode editor for a very simple version of Python and color codded text would make things easier and seems pretty standard.

Comment: Don't know what this is, can't actually find it either.
I wish to design a NEW text format.

Comment: I've been looking into SharpDevelop but I have no clue as to how to write the new keywords into the Rtfwriter.cs class that comes with it...
Any help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a codeproject article about this called [Syntax highlighting textbox written in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SyntaxHighlighting.aspx) which might give you some pointers.

And in case you're going to use a `RichTextBox` I'd suggest this blog post [Some RichTextBox tricks](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/07/07/some-richtextbox-tricks.aspx) .

It might be worth trying to get hold of the book `Dissecting a C# Application: Inside SharpDevelop` which has a chapter called `Chapter 9: Syntax Highlighting` (quite old book but might be able to get a second hand copy).

Comment: Wow thank you I will look into this! before I was stuck using for each word in rtb and the crazy scrolling, flashing, etc.
In fact the hardest part of formatting code in a rtb is selecting all the text between two quotes.
Have any specific tips for that?

Comment: @Yiu: I've not used it in a long time but I seem to remember it was just to use the `Select` method with the start and end postions, as seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s.aspx, or do you mean something else?

Comment: I think this may be it but I'm not sure quite yet, I'll have to test it out.  
But I mean as if I typed:  
$ mikou = Character('魅稿', color="#00FF0F")  
or  
unk "\n何か変な..."  
the "#00FF0F" or "\n何か変な..." (including quotations) would be selected.  
This brings variables into account and this is specifically the most difficult part.
Another example would be like in VB.NET, when I type an apostrophe and the rest of the line turns green for a comment, specifically selecting between the apostrophe and the end of the line.

Comment: The regular Select+SelectLength method is okay for smaller field of text, but definately not for large amounts of text. I've looked into a few things and people are saying I should parse via an XML document containing the coloring rules? I now have a full question for it, but for the most part, I'm still a little stuck. In all other aspects, the program is coming along excellently.